# How to parse a date using Nokogiri in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, parsing, xpath, nokogiri

I am trying to parse this page and pull the date that begins after

```
>p>From Date:
```

I get the error

```
Invalid predicate: //b[text() = '<p>From Date: ' (Nokogiri::XML::XPath::SyntaxError)
```

The xpath from "inspect element" is

```
/html/body/div#timelineItems/table/tbody/tr/td/table.resultsTypes/tbody/tr/td/p
```

This is an example of the code:

```
#/usr/bin/ruby

require 'Nokogiri'
noko = Nokogiri::HTML('china.html')
noko.xpath("//b[text() = '<p>From Date: ").each do |b|
puts b.next_sibling.content.strip
end
```

This is file://china.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

    <html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        
        <title>File </title>

    
      </head>
      <body>
        
            <div id ="timelineItems">
    <H2 id="telegram1"> Title </H2>
            <p><table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
    <td width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="75%">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="resultsTypes">
    <tr>
    <td width="5%" class="hide">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="70%">
    <p>Template: <span class="bidi">ארכיון בן גוריון - מסמך</span></p>
    <p>Title: <a href="http://www.bing.com" title=""><span class="bidi">Meeting in China</span></a></p>

    <p>recipient: David Ben Gurion</p>
    <p>sender: Prime Minister of Union of Burma, Rangoon</p>
    <p>  Sub collection: <span class="bidi">התכתבות > תת-חטיבה מכתב</span></p>
    <p>From Date: 02/14/1936</p>
    <p>Link to file: <span class="bidi">תיק התכתבות  1956 ינואר</span></p>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table></td>
    <td class="actions">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </p>
          </div>
          
    
    </body></html>
```

Amadan's answer 
original.rb

```html
#/usr/bin/ruby

require 'Nokogiri'
noko = Nokogiri::HTML('china.html')
date = noko.at_xpath("//p[starts-with(text(),'From Date: ')]").text()

puts date

formatted = date[/From Date: (.*)/, 1]

puts formatted
```

gives an error `original.rb:5:in '<main>': undefined method 'text' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: `<p>` is a tag, you will never match it with a text matcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use

```
noko = Nokogiri::HTML('china.html')
```

`Nokogiri::HTML` is a shortcut to `Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse`. [The documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/HTML/Document#parse-class_method) says:

> ```
> .parse(string_or_io, url = nil, encoding = nil, options = XML::ParseOptions::DEFAULT_HTML) {|options| ... } ⇒ Object`
> ```
>
> ... `string_or_io` may be a String, or any object that responds to read and close such as an IO, or StringIO. ...

While `'china.html'` is a String, it's not HTML. It appears you're thinking that a filename will suffice, however Nokogiri doesn't open anything, it only understands strings containing markup, either HTML or XML, or an IO-type object that responds to the `read` method. Compare these:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('china.html')
doc.to_html
# => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body><p>china.html</p></body></html>\n"
```

versus:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<html><body><p>foo</p></body></html>')
doc.to_html
# => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body><p>foo</p></body></html>\n"
```

and:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://www.example.org'))
doc.to_html[0..99]
# => "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n<head>\n    <title>Example Domain</title>\n\n    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n    <met"
```

The last works because OpenURI adds the ability to read URLs to `open`, which responds to `read`:

```
open('http://www.example.org').respond_to?(:read) # => true
```

---

Moving on to the question:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

html = <<EOT
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title>File </title>


  </head>
  <body>

        <div id ="timelineItems">
<H2 id="telegram1"> Title </H2>
        <p><table cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="2%">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="75%">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="resultsTypes">
<tr>
<td width="5%" class="hide">&nbsp;</td>
<td width="70%">
<p>Template: <span class="bidi">ארכיון בן גוריון - מסמך</span></p>
<p>Title: <a href="http://www.bing.com" title=""><span class="bidi">Meeting in China</span></a></p>

<p>recipient: David Ben Gurion</p>
<p>sender: Prime Minister of Union of Burma, Rangoon</p>
<p>  Sub collection: <span class="bidi">התכתבות > תת-חטיבה מכתב</span></p>
<p>From Date: 02/14/1936</p>
<p>Link to file: <span class="bidi">תיק התכתבות  1956 ינואר</span></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
</td>
</tr>
</table></td>
<td class="actions">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>

</p>
      </div>


</body></html>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
```

Once the document is parsed, it's easy to find a particular `<p>` tag using the

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="resultsTypes">
```

as a placemarker:

```
from_date = doc.at('table.resultsTypes p[6]').text
# => "From Date: 02/14/1936"
```

---

> It looks like its going to be tougher pulling the title = "Meeting in China" and link = "bing.com"; since they are on the same line.

I'm using [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) to define the path to the desired text. CSS is more easily read than XPath, though XPath is more powerful and descriptive. Nokogiri allows us to use either, and lets us use `search` or `at` with either. `at` is equivalent to `search('some selector').first`. There are also CSS and XPath specific versions of `search` and `at`, described in [`Nokogiri::XML::Node`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node).

```
title_link = doc.at('table.resultsTypes p[2] a')['href'] # => "http://www.bing.com"
title = doc.at('table.resultsTypes p[2] span').text # => "Meeting in China"
```

---

You're trying to use the XPath:

```
/html/body/div#timelineItems/table/tbody/tr/td/table.resultsTypes/tbody/tr/td/p
```

however, it's not valid for the HTML you're working with.

Notice `tbody` in the selector. Look at the HTML, immediately after either of the `<table>` tags, neither occurrence has a `<tbody>` tag, so the XPath is wrong. I suspect that was generated by your browser, which is doing a fix-up of the HTML to add `<tbody>` according to the specification, however Nokogiri doesn't do a fix-up to add `<tbody>` and the HTML doesn't match, causing the search to fail. So, don't rely on the selector defined by the browser, nor should you trust the browser's idea of the actual HTML source.

---

Instead of using an explicit selector, it's better, easier, and smarter, to look for specific way-points in the markup, and use those to navigate to the node(s) you want. Here's an example of doing everything above, only using a placeholder, and a mix of XPath and CSS:

```
doc.at('//p[starts-with(., "Title:")]').text  # => "Title: Meeting in China"
title_node = doc.at('//p[starts-with(., "Title:")]')
title_url = title_node.at('a')['href'] # => "http://www.bing.com"
title = title_node.at('span').text # => "Meeting in China"
```

So, it's fine to mix and match CSS and XPath.

Comment: It looks like its going to be tougher pulling the  title = "Meeting in China" and link = "http://www.bing.com" since they are on the same line.  Can you figure those 2 out?

Comment: No, not harder, just a couple extra steps. Don't confuse a parsed markup file with reading and searching a text file. They're very different animals. I'll add more information later but you can easily figure it out by reading about CSS selectors.

Comment: Thank you. I believe we are supposed to do more than answer the question if there is more to be told. We're here to educate when there is a better way to do something, and explain how things work. We teach them and they teach others and invent new things to teach us.

Comment: On one hand, I mostly agree; but sometimes one does not have time to be very detailed. On the other hand, I also do not fully agree that people need to be told everything: I learned programming by copying BASIC code from a German manual (when I knew no German, and only some English) and fiddling with the code to see what happens if I change the order of the lines, or the parameter values - full scientific method at 10 years of age :P which served me well later in life.

Comment: I learned all my languages that way. There's always time to be detailed if we ignore the race for points and concentrate on good answers. If someone already understands why they should do something the right way and is missing a single detail I answer with that point. If they don't have an idea how to do it, I give an overview and expect them to dig in and learn the details. Most answers are somewhere in between.

Answer (score 1):

```
from_date = noko.at_xpath('//p[starts-with(text(), "From Date:")]').text()
date = from_date[/From Date: (.*)/, 1]
# => "02/14/1936"
```

EDIT:

Explanation: Get the first node (`#at_xpath`) anywhere in the document (`//`) such that (`[...]`) text content (`text()`) starts with (`starts-with(string, stringStart)`) `"From Date"` (`"From Date:"`), and take its text content (`#text()`), storing it (`=`) into the variable `from_date` (`from_date`). Then, extract the first group (`#[regexp, 1]`) from that text (`from_date`) by using the regular expression (`/.../`) that matches the literal characters `"From Date: "`, followed by any number (`*`) of any characters (`.`), that will be captured (`(...)`) in the first capture group to be extracted by `#[regexp, 1]`.

Also,

> Amadan's answer [...] gives an error

I did not notice that your Nokogiri construction is broken, as explained by the Tin Man. The line `noko = Nokogiri::HTML('china.html')` (which was not a part of my answer) will give you a single node document that only has the text `"china.html"` in it, and no `<p>` nodes at all.

Comment: please explain what you did here